# Android Tab Onclick listener

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Swipe is working on TabLayout click is not working ?
How to add click listener on TabLayout ?

Inside Activity

> ```
>     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
>     setupViewPager(viewPager);
>
>
>     tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
>     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
>
>     viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
>     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>             viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>
>         }
>     });
>
> class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>
>     private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
>     private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
>         super(manager);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>         return mFragmentList.get(position);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public int getCount() {
>         return mFragmentList.size();
>     }
>
>     public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
>         mFragmentList.add(fragment);
>         mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>         return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

```
    adapter.addFragment(new TabOneFragment(), "TAB1");

    adapter.addFragment(new TabTwoFragement(), "TAB2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Layout xml files

> ```
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:tabMode="fixed"
>         app:tabGravity="fill"/>
>
>     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>         android:id="@+id/viewpager"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
> ```

how can I add onclick on tabs ?
please help!!

Comment: my version of libraries  25.3.1

Comment: android:elevation="6dp"
needed for click why ?

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
MyApplyFragment myApplyFragment = new MyApplyFragment();

adapter.addFragment(searchFragment, "SearchFragment");
adapter.addFragment(myApplyFragment, "MyApplyFragment");

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }

    }
```